# Spring MVC 3 + Maven + Hibernate tomcat don't start

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven, tomcat

I start this project 6 months ago. With 4 weeks ago I've formatted my computer. After I put my project again on my Tomcat server 8.5, and when I put my project in eclipse I had a warning about mysql-connector-java. My server don't start and i have this error:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PacientAnalysis]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PacientAnalysis]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
to start component
[org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@336ad8c3]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4891)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5026)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
to initialize component
[org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@75d9e038]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
(bad signature)     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 13 more
Apr 23, 2018 8:57:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493) Caused
by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Apr 23, 2018 8:57:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493) Caused
by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

I am using now: 
JAVA_HOME: 1.8.0_161,
MAVEN: 3.5.3,
TOMCAT: 8.5.30.

Here are my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
    <artifactId>PacientAnalysis</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PacientAnalysis Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>PacientAnalysis</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

UPDATE: The solution was to go into my .m2 folder and delete the repository folder. After you did that open eclipse IDE and **right click** on project go to **Maven** **Update Project**. After that go in **Properties** **Deployment Assembly** remove the **maven dependencies** (if eclipse don't do that) or go to **Add** Java Build Path Entries and choose **maven dependencies**.

If you don't know like me where is the m2 folder look at this: [link](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/)

And solution what work for me it's here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788190/error-with-pom-xml-in-mvc-template-project?rq=1)

Comment: Can you try rebuilding the war and redeploy the same, looks like some issue with the .war you deployed.

Comment: How can i rebuild and redeploy the war? Anil Kumar Athuluri

Comment: "mvn clean package" should clean and build the war.

Comment: when i type mvn clean package, project build failure and I have this error "Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamDriver
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo"

Comment: I am trying to do "maven clean package" to the other project from my old workspace and It give the same error. I think is a problem from my maven configuration I don't know.